# What's the best strategy for get/setting metadata on Ruby methods at runtime?

Tags: ruby, extension-methods, metaprogramming, metadata

I have a class with some methods. It's supersekret but I've reproduced what I can here.

```
Class RayGun
  # flashes red light
  # requires confirmation
  # makes "zowowowowowow" sound
  def stun!
    # ...
  end

  # flashes blue light
  # does not require confirmation
  # makes "trrrtrtrtrrtrtrtrtrtrtr" sound
  def freeze!
    # ...
  end

  # doesn't flash any lights
  # does not require confirmation
  # makes Windows startup sound
  def killoblast!
    # ...
  end
end
```

I want to be able to, at runtime, interrogate the class about one of the methods and receive a hash or struct like so:

```
  {:lights => 'red', :confirmation => false, :sound => 'windows'}
```

What's the best way of doing this? Obviously you could have separate YAML file alongside and set up a convention to relate the two, but ideally I want code and metadata in one place.

The most promising idea I can come up with is something like this:

```
class RayGun
  cattr_accessor :metadata
  def self.register_method(hsh)
    define_method(hsh.name, hsh.block)
    metadata[hsh[:name]] = hsh
  end

  register_method({
    :name => 'stun!', 
    :lights => 'red', 
    :confirmation => 'true', 
    :sound => 'zowowo',
    :block => Proc.new do
      # code goes here
   })

   # etc.
end
```

Anyone got some better ideas? Am I barking up a very wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another strategy poking around http://github.com/wycats/thor/tree. Thor lets you write stuff like this:

```
Class RayGun < Thor
  desc "Flashes red light and makes zowowowowow sound"
  method_options :confirmation => :required
  def stun!
    # ...
  end
end
```

It manages this by using the (undocumented) hook `Module#method_added`. It works like this:

1. Call to `Thor#desc` and
   `Thor#method_options` set instance
   variables `@desc`,
   `@method_options`.
2. Defining method `stun!` calls
   `Thor#method_added(meth)`
3. `Thor#method_added` registers
   `Task.new(meth.to_s, @desc,
   @method_options)` (roughly speaking)
   and unsets `@desc`,
   `@method_options`.
4. It's now ready for the next method

Neat! So neat that I am going to accept my own answer :)

Comment: method_added may be undocumented on rdoc, but it is on a documentation linked by the official site: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ospace.html

Answer (score 2):

Just a little beautyfication:

```
class RayGun
  cattr_accessor :metadata
  def self.register_method(name, hsh, &block)
    define_method(name, block)
    metadata[name] = hsh
  end

  register_method( 'stun!',
    :lights => 'red', 
    :confirmation => 'true', 
    :sound => 'zowowo',
    ) do
      # code goes here
  end

   # etc.
end
```

You do lose easy access to the original closure, but probably don't need it.

To answer the question, it doesn't look bad, you could do something a little more convetional but probably good enough:

```
class RayGun
  cattr_accessor :metadata

  @metadata[:stun!] = {:lights => 'red', 
                        :confirmation => 'true', 
                        :sound => 'zowowo'}
  def stun!
    # ...
  end

   # etc.
end
```

In the original example register_method is public, if you planned to use it that way then the second option becomes less usefull because it doesn't ensure consistency.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [YARD](http://github.com/lsegal/yard/tree/master) tool which lets you add metadata to methods.  I'm pretty sure it just sticks the metadata into the `rdoc` files you generate, but you could easily build off of that to get runtime information.